# Partial syntax highlighting with Python and MacVim

Tags: python, vim, macvim

MacVim is driving me crazy. The syntax is only partially highlighted. What am I missing--I don't get it.

For example `x = 5 * 10`
The `*` should highlight, but it's doesn't. `==` `+` etc. don't highlight.

Also the `self` doesn't highlight. (Yes, that's not a keyword, but still).

I'd be great if the arguments inside a function highlighted, too.

I'm using one of the more popular [python syntax scripts](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=790).

Adding `let python_highlight_all = 1` to my .vimrc file doesn't work either.

Comment: This sounds like you need to set up a theme or formatting that changes the colours for those operators.

Comment: have you tried to save the file as `xxx.py` and type `:sy on`

Comment: I've been using it with python files. I even tried `:set filetype=python` and toggled the `syntax on` to make sure it works.

Comment: -1: This sounds like a feature request for the syntax script to me.  You should contact the author or hack the script to adjust it to your needs.  As is, neither operators nor `self` should be highlighted, and highlighting function arguments is tricky if not impossible with syntax scripts.

Comment: If you don't like the ide, why not eclipse?

Comment: Actually I like Eclipse, and I've been using an IDE as of late.

Answer (score 0):

Here’s what Python looks like for me in MacVim:

[image]

and in regular Vim:

[image]

Keywords and literals are highlighted but other symbols aren’t. Do you see something different or do you see the same thing but expect to see something different?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting in your `~/.vim/after/sytax/` a file `python.vim` containing both lines

```
syn match   pythonOperator  "\(+\|-\|=\|*\|/\|\.\|,\|;\|:\|<\|>\|!\|%\|\~\|&\|\^\||\)"
syn keyword pythonStatement self
```

I agree with Ferdinand Beyer that

> highlighting function arguments is tricky if not impossible with syntax scripts.

Answer (score 0):

I imported my vim settings from a linux machine to a mac and had issues with partial syntax highlighting. In the end, it turned out to be an issue with the way the mac terminal displayed my vim colour scheme. Try changing your colour scheme `:colo desert` to see if it fixes the issue.